# In Redux, how to retrieve values from an API and show the result in the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a Redux project where I am trying to retrieve the values from an API server using axios library.After retrieving the values from the server,I am trying to save it in the application state.I am doing the API call in my **Actions**.The Actions.js file is as shown below:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_POSTS = 'fetch_posts';

let token = localStorage.token
if(!token)
  token = localStorage.token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(-8)
const API = 'http://localhost:3001';
const headers = {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' :'token'
                }

export function fetchPosts() {
  const URL = `${API}/posts`;
  const request = axios.get(URL,{headers});

  return dispatch => {
        request.then(({data}) => {
          dispatch({
            type : FETCH_POSTS,
            payload : data
          })
        })
  }
}
```

After retrieving the data,I am trying to console.log the object returned in my Component.My Component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions';
import _ from 'lodash';

class PostsIndex extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();

  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.props.posts); //returns an empty object

    return(
      <div>
        Posts
      </div>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { posts: state.posts };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(PostsIndex);
```

The object that I am trying to retrieve from the API server is given below:

```
const defaultData = {
  "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd": {
    id: '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd',
    timestamp: 1467166872634,
    title: 'Udacity is the best place to learn React',
    body: 'Everyone says so after all.',
    author: 'thingtwo',
    category: 'react',
    voteScore: 6,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 2
  },
  "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": {
    id: '6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez',
    timestamp: 1468479767190,
    title: 'Learn Redux in 10 minutes!',
    body: 'Just kidding. It takes more than 10 minutes to learn technology.',
    author: 'thingone',
    category: 'redux',
    voteScore: -5,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 0
  }
}
```

Now,I can see the object with the 2 values returned from the API server in my network response.But,if I try to console.log the value of the same posts(The result of the api call is saved as "posts" state in the store), it returns an empty object.What am I doing wrong, can anybody please help me with this?

**Reducer files**

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import PostReducer from './PostsReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    loading: false,
    posts: PostReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

PostReducer.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_POSTS } from '../actions';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
     return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'id');

    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, you aren't rerendering `PostsIndex`, *after* `fetchPosts` finishes so you're always seeing an empty object. You cannot see the updated Redux store value *unless you rerender your component*. React Redux does not do this for you. Use state to trigger a rerender, such as a loading indicator:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchPosts())
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
    });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      this.state.loading ? 
        /* loading UI could go here */
      :
        /* you can access this.props.posts here */
    <div>
  );
}
```

And I wouldn't use `mapDispatchToProps` in `connect`. Change your `connect` line to this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostsIndex);
```

This is because `dispatch` allows for promise chaining with Redux Thunk.

Once your post fetching finishes, the promise will resolve and state will be set (assuming Redux Thunk). This state setting will rerender the component and display the fetched posts.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I tried as you mentioned,but I am getting an error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: @pranami Are you using redux thunk?

Comment: yeah,I am using redux-thunk.I have my project here in my github.This is the link: https://github.com/PranamiBG/Readable-project/tree/master/src.Can you please check once

Comment: @pranami Actually, try doing `return request.then(…)`

Comment: The error is gone now,but if I try to console.log the posts state in componentDidMount() after the dispatch line that I added,I am still getting an empty object.

Comment: @pranami That's because the fetch hasn't finished yet when you're `console.log`ing... `console.log` inside the `then` after the `setState`.

Comment: I tried putting the console.log after setState,but still it is returning an empty object.This is my code: componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPosts())
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading : false
      });
      console.log(this.props.posts)      
    })
  }

Comment: sure,just give me a min.I will add the file in an edit above

Comment: I have added the reducer files at the end in an edit above.Can you please check.

Comment: Wow,it's working perfectly now.Thank you so much for your continuous effort in solving this.Really appreciate it.Thanks once again. :D :)

Comment: If you don't mind, 1 last question I want to ask.So, while returning the state reducer,both the post and payload are added.I mean the payload has the response from the api call right?So,I am finding it bit confusing how both are being returned.If you don't mind,can you please explain little bit how this is working actually?

Comment: @pranami Sure. So what `{ ...state.posts, ...action.payload }` does is take the *existing posts* (if there are any) and adds them to the new posts from the request. This is object spread syntax.